# Zend/db/Sql/ query syntax

Tags: sql, zend-framework2, zend-db

I am starting with `Zend Framework 2` , I want to make a routing choice with the role of My user and I must write `getRoleByID($id)` ,

then 
How can'I write

`"  Select 'role' from user where ('id' = $id) "` with Zend\Db\Sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example Using Select:

```
$select = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Select('user');
$select->columns(array('role'));
$where = new Where();
$where->equalTo('id', $id);
$select->where($where);
/**
 * Simple example of executing a query...
 */
$stmt = $this->getSql()->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$results = $stmt->execute();
/* @var $results \Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result */

if( ! $results->count()) {
     // do something, none found...
}

$row = $results->current(); 
return $row['role'];

// if you had multiple results to iterate over:
//$resultSet = new \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet();
//$resultSet->initialize($results);    
//$array = $resultSet->toArray();
//foreach($resultSet as $row) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: thank you for your reponce , it's very helpful . Just one question , i must execute the query with 
// $stmt = $this->getSql()->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$results = $stmt->execute(); 
// to can compare with the result ??